# python code returns a datatimestamp for a file that isn't in S3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an S3 bucket that contains a folder (inbox/) with 3 files in it:

[image]

I am running this pythoncode:

```
import os
import boto3

bucket = s3.Bucket('MyBucket')
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    head, tail = os.path.split(key.key)
    if key.key.startswith('inbox/') and tail is not None:
       head, tail = os.path.split(key.key)
       print(str(tail)+''+str(key.last_modified))
```

this code returns the following:

[image]

I have no idea of how to get rid of the first timestamp. It seems to be the creationdatetime of the folder (/inbox in this case...). I only want to have the files and datetimestamps from those files in the result. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can check the key is endswith `/` or not.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('MyBucket')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='inbox'):
    if not obj.key.endswith('/'):
        filename = obj.key.split('/')[-1]
        print(f'{filename} {obj.last_modified}')
```

Comment: Thanks! I am embarrassed.... still not clear though why it shows an object that isn't there.....

Comment: it is not a filesystem but object storage with key, so the folder is actually just an object and it is the reason why the key appear with the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
import os
import time
from pprint import pprint


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('ybagarka.docker.swarm')
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    head, tail = os.path.split(key.key)
    if key.key.startswith('tfstate_files') and tail is not None:
        head, tail = os.path.split(key.key)
        summaryDetails=s3.ObjectSummary('ybagarka.docker.swarm',key.key)
        timeFormat=summaryDetails.last_modified
        formatedTime=timeFormat.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        print(formatedTime)
        print(head)
        print("The filename is "+head+" last modified day is "+formatedTime)
```

**Output:**

```
2019-11-15
tfstate_files
The filename is tfstate_files last modified day is 2019-11-15
```